# Safest way to open PDFs on Android and iOS?

Tags: web-browser, android, ios, sandbox, pdf

I was checking out [Qubes' way](https://micahflee.com/2016/07/how-qubes-makes-handling-pdfs-way-safer/) of creating safe PDFs, but unless you use Qubes as a daily driver (and use DispVMs to open PDFs) it's still not viable to just use it to create image-based PDFs if you have very huge documents in them. I really hope they someday manage to find a way to create safe PDFs without the increase in size and loss of functionalities. If there already is a way, please tell me, but until then I was considering other options.

As far as I could see, the least risky readers to see PDFs in should be the browsers' embedded PDF readers, as they can use browser sandboxing and they're pretty simple as well. On the PC I guess opening PDFs in Firefox/Chrome/Edge should be the way then. But what about Android and iOS? The browsers for them don't have an embedded PDF reader. What could one do to have at least that sort of security on those OSes?

Comment: Well...on Android and iOS, every app basically has sandboxing.

Comment: Really? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

GrapheneOS devs found a good way.
" Simple Android PDF viewer based on pdf.js and content providers. The app doesn't require any permissions. The PDF stream is fed into the sandboxed WebView without giving it access to content or files. CSP is used to enforce that the JavaScript and styling properties within the WebView are entirely static. "

https://github.com/GrapheneOS/PdfViewer

Comment: Isn't `pdf.js` developed by the Mozilla Foundation? If so, I think it's worth mentioning and giving credit.